# How to sort a dict by the values inside its keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary, ordereddict

So I have something like this:

```
[
{
    "arg1":
          {"valueone" : 2, "valuetwo": 5"},
},
{
    "arg2":
          {"valueone" : 7, "valuetwo": 3"},
},
{
    "arg3":
          {"valueone" : 3, "valuetwo": 7"},
},
{
    "arg4":
          {"valueone" : 4, "valuetwo": 6"},
},
{
    "arg5":
          {"valueone" : 9, "valuetwo": 5"},
},

]
```

I want to sort them by their `valueone` s. I have a knowledge of OrderedDict, however I got some troubles to do this.

An expected result would be:

```
[
{
    "arg5":
          {"valueone" : 9, "valuetwo": 5"},
},
{
    "arg2":
          {"valueone" : 7, "valuetwo": 3"},
},
{
    "arg4":
          {"valueone" : 4, "valuetwo": 6"},
},
{
    "arg3":
          {"valueone" : 3, "valuetwo": 7"},
},

{
    "arg1":
          {"valueone" : 2, "valuetwo": 5"},
},


]
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't see any sorted order in it.

Comment: Have you looked into `sorted`? With it you can use a custom lambda as key.

Comment: So you have a list of dictionaries? And you want to sort that list? Or you have a dictionary and want to make a sorted `OrderedDict`?

Comment: Both your input and your output are list of dictionaries.

Comment: Which Python Version?

Comment: @jdehesa I have an exact copy of the sample above. a list of dicts, which have another dict inside and I want to order them based on the value I said.

Comment: @taurus05 will try..

Comment: @AdrianJałoszewski 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the key parameter of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) combined with `reverse=True`,  for instance:

```
data = [
    {"arg1": {"valueone": 2, "valuetwo": "5"}},
    {"arg2": {"valueone": 7, "valuetwo": "3"}},
    {"arg3": {"valueone": 3, "valuetwo": "7"}},
    {"arg4": {"valueone": 4, "valuetwo": "6"}},
    {"arg5": {"valueone": 9, "valuetwo": "5"}}
]

result = sorted(data, key=lambda x: next(x["valueone"] for x in x.values()), reverse=True)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'arg5': {'valuetwo': '5', 'valueone': 9}}, {'arg2': {'valuetwo': '3', 'valueone': 7}}, {'arg4': {'valuetwo': '6', 'valueone': 4}}, {'arg3': {'valuetwo': '7', 'valueone': 3}}, {'arg1': {'valuetwo': '5', 'valueone': 2}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Since python3, `dict.keys()` is not subscriptable, so `z.keys()[0]` would fail. So best to use:

```
>>> res = sorted(x, key=lambda z: next(iter(z.values()))['valueone'], reverse=True)
>>> pprint.pprint(res)
[{'arg5': {'valueone': 9, 'valuetwo': '5'}},
 {'arg2': {'valueone': 7, 'valuetwo': '3'}},
 {'arg4': {'valueone': 4, 'valuetwo': '6'}},
 {'arg3': {'valueone': 3, 'valuetwo': '7'}},
 {'arg1': {'valueone': 2, 'valuetwo': '5'}}]
```

Try this

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(x)
[{'arg1': {'valueone': 2, 'valuetwo': 5}},
 {'arg2': {'valueone': 7, 'valuetwo': 3}},
 {'arg3': {'valueone': 3, 'valuetwo': 7}},
 {'arg4': {'valueone': 4, 'valuetwo': 6}},
 {'arg5': {'valueone': 9, 'valuetwo': 5}}]
>>> sorted_ = sorted(x, key=lambda z: z[z.keys()[0]]['valueone'], reverse=True)
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted_)
[{'arg5': {'valueone': 9, 'valuetwo': 5}},
 {'arg2': {'valueone': 7, 'valuetwo': 3}},
 {'arg4': {'valueone': 4, 'valuetwo': 6}},
 {'arg3': {'valueone': 3, 'valuetwo': 7}},
 {'arg1': {'valueone': 2, 'valuetwo': 5}}]
```

Comment: thank you too. this one also works. didn't thought it was this easy